Is it possible to design a "paywalled" Web API that is meant to be consumed securely from a web frontend?
Let's say I want to design an API that does something useful that people pay monthly to consume. Let's say an endpoint for this API is the following:
https://www.example.com/api/GetMeaningOfLife
Since the API is "paywalled", consumers of the API must prove they are paying customers of the API before it will work.
A straightforward way of architecting the API is such that when POSTing to the API, the client must provide a secret key that identifies they are a paying customer to the API. If no secret key is provided, the API fails.
When in the context of a web application, to ensure the secret key remains secret, one can just consume the API on the server side, and pass along the result of the API call to the resulting web page. This way there is no way for users to snoop around in the browser's developer console to find the secret key, since the API consumption is done on the server.
However, what if the API is meant to be called from the frontend (i.e. JavaScript)? How would a paywalled API like this be designed, such that it is meant to be called via JavaScript from a frontend, but also ensure others cannot just copy/paste some secret key from your site and start impersonating you on their own site to access an API you are paying for? What options are there?

what if the API is meant to be called from the frontend - then it's up to that API to provide a mechanism to secure itself against such potential issues.

@Bravo Is there an article I can read somewhere about how to secure "paywalled" APIs that are meant to be called from the frontend? Or perhaps you can give a summary on how one would be architected?

are you asking the question as a consumer or provider of this 3rd party API?

@Bravo I'm actually asking as both the designer of the API and the consumer. I rephrased my original question, see my edits.

Ahh, OK - well, then you'll need to research how to do that - I've never created such an API, so I'll take my leave - however, their will be some sort of backend to backend process to authenticate a session or some such

Edit by user3163495: this answer was given before the original question was reworded.

No. In order to call the third-party api while keeping the API Key secret a server side request should be made instead (i.e: A request on the backend) and the response of that request should then be sent to your frontend/web client.
Any request sent on the frontend would be logged in the network console on the browser devtools where you can get details about the request including any authorization headers.

To keep your secret key SECRET, It is better you set up your API Request on your backend server, such that the request is securely handled on the backend and the response of that request is sent over to the frontend through the existing secure API integration between your frontend and your backend.
Extra tips include:

Storing your SECRET Key in an environment variable on the Backend
Using an API gateway or service to manage and authenticate API requests


Is it even possible to secure a "paywalled" API that's meant to be called from the frontend? If so, how would such an API be architected?

@Bravo I'm actually asking as both the designer of the API and the consumer. I rephrased my original question, see my edits.
